# Install libpq-dev on Mac OS?

Tags: mac, postgresql

Does anyone know how I can install [libpq-dev](http://packages.debian.org/sid/libpq-dev) on Mac OS 10.6? It's a pre-requisite for something else I want to install.

There doesn't seem to be a macport for it, so how can I install it on a Mac?

Answer (score 67):

Consider using Homebrew

```
brew install postgresql
```

It'll give you the necessary headers.

Comment: I don't want to install Postgresql on my Mac! I have Postgres already running in a Docker container. Just want to make this dam pg gem running. Any way to install only some kind of pg-dev header packages?

Comment: Well one thing to consider is just cause you install pg via homebrew, it doesn't mean you have to run the deamon (server).  Just use the client that way, I doubt it takes up much space anyways.

Comment: It does take up significant space: `brew` requires 1Gb of its own git repo in order to function at all.

Answer (score 25):

You can install libpq (dev files are included) alone using homebrew.

```
brew install libpq
```

The include files and libs are then available in the following folders:

```
/usr/local/opt/libpq/lib
/usr/local/opt/libpq/include
```

Answer (score 4):

When I've search in ports I've found this:

```
port search libpq
libpqxx @3.0.2 (databases, devel)
    Official C++ client API for PostgreSQL

libpqxx26 @2.6.9 (databases, devel)
    Official C++ client API for PostgreSQL
```

You can try one of those.

Comment: libpq is C connector library while libpqxx is C++. In other words - this most definitely will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Using macports, this worked for me:

```
sudo port install postgresql96
sudo port select --set postgresql postgresql96
```

I believe this installs all the postgres client tools and libs, while macports has a separate port for installing the server, i.e. `postgresql96-server`.